# Receiving "action must not be null" after invoking a Flow from an Aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, visual-workflow

Issue: Receiving "action must not be null" after invoking a Flow from an Aura component.

Setup:

In my application, I am utilizing a master flow to collect information. The process is laid out on a Lightning Record Page, with a progress tracker on the left and the form on the right.  The process is driven by a master flow with 11 sub-flows driving each section.

When the user is in the last two steps, (Review and Submit and Submitted) the sub-flows invoke a lwc wrapped in an aura component. The lwc has sections for all previous steps and has buttons to allow the user to edit previously entered information. Each section has an Edit button.

Problem:

When the Edit button is invoked, the aura component will invoke the Flow responsible for the intake of the section. Herein lies the problem. The button will take me to the Flow. I can modify the information and when I press the "Next" button associated with the flow, the modified information is saved. However, upon pressing the next button, I receive the message: action must not be null.

Troubleshooting:

Invoked the flow as a url. This works, but I lose the Lightning Record Layout during the edit.
When the Flow is invoked, it is running all actions until the next screen. If there is no “next” screen, then it completes the flow. After completion of the flow, the error is thrown.
Browsers used: (all on Macbook) 
Chrome Version 81.0.4044.122 (Official Build) (64-bit
Edge Version 81.0.416.62 (Official build) (64-bit)
Safari Version 13.1 (14609.1.20.111.8)
In Chrome Dev Tools, I am checking the Console and Network panels. When I edit a section (invoke the Flow) and press the next button. upon reviewing the Network tab, I see the FlowRuntime executed twice. It is in the second Runtime where the error shows itself.

Comment: We discovered today that we are having this same issue after the Summer '20 release.  Were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Hello Chuck and Peter,

I worked on this one. This is identified as a bug. Known issue:
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001Sp5FQAS

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this by using a modal window to support the action. Remember, I am running a master Flow which calls a series of Sub-flows. In one Sub-Flow, I am calling an Aura component to invoke another Sub-flow, and then return to the first Sub-flow.

In the Aura component, I, instead of simply invoking the sub-flow, I invoke it within a modal. Within the modal, upon completing the form, I navigate back to the record, which, through Lightning Pages, and the master flow, takes me to the starting point.